# How to create animated graphs with csv data in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

Create a line chart when you have the following csv data I want the points to move on that line graph according to time.

```
TIME,CH1,CH2,CH3,CH4
01:39.1,988,988,992,988
01:39.1,988,988,992,988
01:39.1,988,992,988,992
01:39.2,988,988,992,992
01:39.2,988,992,988,988
01:39.2,988,988,992,988
01:39.2,988,992,988,988
01:39.2,988,992,992,988
```

I was able to create a line chart using plotly. However, I am unable to proceed to the next step. Please help me.

```
pip install plotly==5.10.0
```

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('No14_01.csv', index_col=0)
data = [
        go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['CH1'], name='CH1'),
        go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['CH2'], name='CH2'),
        go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['CH3'], name='CH3'),
        go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['CH4'], name='CH4'),
        ]

layout = go.Layout(
                    title='No14 PPM Length',
                    xaxis={'title': 'TIME'},
                    yaxis={'title': 'PPM Length'},
                    font={'size': 18},
                    width=1000,
                    height=600
                    )
                    
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't usually work with animations, I created an animation based on the [examples](https://plotly.com/python/animations/#simple-play-button) in the reference, using a time axis. As for the intent of the question, I create the code from the understanding that I want to animate a graph drawn with two time points from the data presented.
Since there are only two frames because of the two time points, I adjust the interval between frames to 500. If you have a large number of frames, reduce this value.

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = [
        go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['CH1'], name='CH1'),
        go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['CH2'], name='CH2'),
        go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['CH3'], name='CH3'),
        go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['CH4'], name='CH4'),
        ]

layout = go.Layout(
    title='No14 PPM Length',
    xaxis={'title': 'TIME'},
    yaxis={'title': 'PPM Length'},
    font={'size': 18},
    width=1000,
    height=600,
    updatemenus=[dict(
        type="buttons",
        buttons=[dict(label="Start",
                      method="animate",
                      args=[None, dict(frame=dict(duration=400, redraw=True), 
                                                             transition=dict(duration=4),
                                                             fromcurrent=True,
                                                             mode='immediate'
                                                            )]),
                ],
        direction='left',
        pad=dict(r=10, t=87),
        showactive=False,
        x=0.1,
        xanchor='right',
        y=0,
        yanchor='top'
    )])

frames = [go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=df.query('TIME == "01:39.1"').index, y=df.query('TIME == "01:39.1"')['CH1'], name='CH1'),
                         go.Scatter(x=df.query('TIME == "01:39.1"').index, y=df.query('TIME == "01:39.1"')['CH2'], name='CH2'),
                         go.Scatter(x=df.query('TIME == "01:39.1"').index, y=df.query('TIME == "01:39.1"')['CH3'], name='CH3'),
                         go.Scatter(x=df.query('TIME == "01:39.1"').index, y=df.query('TIME == "01:39.1"')['CH4'], name='CH4')]),
        go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=df.query('TIME == "01:39.2"').index, y=df.query('TIME == "01:39.2"')['CH1'], name='CH1'),
                         go.Scatter(x=df.query('TIME == "01:39.2"').index, y=df.query('TIME == "01:39.2"')['CH2'], name='CH2'),
                         go.Scatter(x=df.query('TIME == "01:39.2"').index, y=df.query('TIME == "01:39.2"')['CH3'], name='CH3'),
                         go.Scatter(x=df.query('TIME == "01:39.2"').index, y=df.query('TIME == "01:39.2"')['CH4'], name='CH4')])]

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout, frames=frames)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.
However, this is not the graph I want to make. My apologies.
What I want to make is a graph like Moving Point on a Curve, which can be found at https://plotly.com/python/animations/.
I would like to know how to make it.

Comment: From your question, it never occurred to me that you would want to make an example of the reference in your comment. Without being specific about how you want the current data to be presented, there is no way to answer your question. How do you want the current output to work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I want to make a Point move on a line chart, like Moving Point on a Curve on https://plotly.com/python/animations/.